# How to use views contextual filter default argument "Taxonomy term id in url"

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I am following the guide http://www.metachunk.com/blog/adding-related-content-view-drupal-7 to make a related content block.  I have 2 taxonomies that my content is tagged with.  But the contextual filters are not working.

I think it is because the path is node/[nid] and does not contain a taxonomy term id.  How can I fix this so that views can figure out what terms a node is tagged with?  Should I provide the default argument another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you figured this out? If so could you share your answer?

I do not think the problem is that the path follows any pattern.  As long as you create a path that identifies the location of a term and you configure the contextual filter correctly.  eg. example.com/whatever-you-want/any-term will work as long as the view path is example.com/whatever-you-want/%.  The 'any-term' must be a term in a vocabulary defined for the contextual filter and validation must be set to identify it.

Comment: I didn't figure this out, instead I ended up using similar entries: http://drupal.org/project/similar it compares data in MySQL to determine what content is similar rather than relying on taxonomies.  If you can confirm that your answer works I'll accept it, but I abandoned this approach so I will not be able to test unfortunately.

Comment: I have used the format I described successfully. I will also check out the similar module! :)

Answer (score 0):

Youre probably better off using panels to populate the view pane/block  with the correct context (term id) but you can also delegate views to do this for you using the information you have (nid) and adding a relationship in views. Depending on if youre trying to list the terms or items mathicn the terms it is done slightly differently but this shoul dget you headed in the right direction. Good luck!